# Communication methods between two GAE services in the same project

Tags: google-app-engine, urlfetch, gae-module

On Google App Engine, when a project has more than one service and these services in the same project need to communicate to one another, is there any way to send a message to another service for calling function apart from using URLFetch api?

Comment: are you talking about a micro service architecture in your project?

Comment: @Ook it'd help if you gave the language and structure of your project

Comment: @Michael Meyer Yes, I mean GAE micro services in a GAE project

Comment: @Samson I am using Go on GAE and planning to use micro services in the same GAE project.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [Task Queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/).

The queue definitions are an app-level configuration applicable to all services/modules. So tasks can be enqueued into any queue by any service/module and each queue can be targeted to (serviced by) a specific service/module.

Comment: Thats how im doing it in my apps. I have a web frontend on one service, and backends that are using more powerful instances that only run for long enough to service the queue requests